# Password required to power off Android device

Tags: android

I wanted to see if it was possible to have an app that can monitor the shutdown intent and require a password/pin to proceed with the power off. Ideally I would like to have it before the power off menu appears after holding the power button, so before the menu is shown with options like "Power off" and "Airplane Mode" the user would be required to enter a password/pin. I know this might not be possible without rooting the device. Just wanted to see if something like this was possible without having root access.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was thinking it might be possible to monitor the shutdown intent when the power off option has been selected and require a pass-code before it executes. Similar to some apps that allow you to require pass-codes before launching apps. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @ashkash have you found your's answer?

Comment: no its not possible every android device comes with the built in hardware power off button and long press will automatically shutdown

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the battery pulling out, the Nexus 4 solves this.

About the intent android.intent.action.SHUTDOWN- It sounds like it is possible to create an application with this logic:

1. monitor the android.intent.action.SHUTDOWN
2. ask the user to type the password or the pattern
3. If the password correct, it announces that the application is ready for shutdown
4. Otherwise, just hold on the password/pattern screen and provide the user another chance (repeat this forever until the right pass is typed...)

Comment: and publish the link here for us to download the app :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, neither Google, the phone manufacturers nor the carriers want to provide/enable such functionality. They want to encourage the theft of your phone as they make money from it, forcing you to get a replacement device! Making your device theft-proof, (something VERY easy to do if they wanted to,) is not something those bastards care to do.

Now, for the good news:

I have Samsung Galaxy Note 3 on Verizon.

I just installed "Smart Locksreen Protector" app, and it works like a charm, disabling the power menu all together.

I have a metal bumper on my phone. It requires a micro screwdriver to remove! I could make it even more secure by replacing the micro Phillips screws with some rare screws. This prevents someone from easily popping the battery out! They'd need tools, or something to cut the bumper off with.

Now I'm trying to find a good app that will take photos of the intruder whenever the enter the wrong pin.

Answer (score 1):

I have searched for some sort of app in the past that would prevent power-off without first entering pass-code, but came up with no solution.

Along the way, I realized this - if you're trying to prevent the phone from being shutoff by unauthorized user, it will be futile.

All they need to do is pull the battery.

Comment: I agree that pulling the battery is always an option, but on phones with a non-removable battery an app that forces a pass-code before shutdown might give a user more time to remotely locate lost or stolen devices. Just not sure if it is possible to monitor the shutdown intent and require a pass-code before it executes without having root access.

Comment: In phones like the Moto Z, the battery is integrated in the phone.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest i could find.

Smart Lockscreen protector

It prevents shutdown from the lockdown screen.

Answer (score 0):

There is an intent - *android.intent.action.SHUTDOWN* which does get broadcasted so services can safely clean up gracefully.

Other than that, no, cannot override the powering off as once the user confirms to shutdown, that's it, no going back!

Comment: Got it. Was just hoping there was a way to halt the execution of the shutdown so an app can require a pass-code once they get the shutdown intent broadcast. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty old, so not sure if anyone's still looking into this, but what if you were to reassign the hardware button to something other than power? /system/usr/keylayout keeps all of the key files. If you had a phone that both did not have a removable battery and also did not allow a soft-boot with the power key outside of the os, you could hypothetically try that. Not 100% sure it's possible, and I really don't have the desire to make my work-phone terminal reboot only, but it might be worth investigation.

Answer (score 0):

You can require a pin/pattern but the long press of the power button turns off almost all the mobile devices.. it is hardware related..

Answer (score 0):

For some Xperia devices it is useless, unless the thief was a very stupid guy. Most Non-removable battery devices have a little button somewhere on the back that you might press for a while using a nail or somerhing sharp enoght and it basically "disconnects" the battery and inmediately shuts the phone off. We use it all the time for technical support issues (when the phone freezes out and you need to force shutoff) and it doesnt require any user additional steps, you press abd and then phone deads inmediatelly.